# File conversion issue in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, file-upload

i am using this code in time of file uploading

```
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        filePath1 = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myVoice.caf"];// specify your audioname
        NSLog(@"***************************");
        NSLog(@"%@",filePath1);


        NSDictionary *fileAttributes1 = [fileManager attributesOfItemAtPath:filePath1 error: NULL];
        NSNumber *fileSize1 = [fileAttributes1 objectForKey:NSFileSize];
        NSLog(@"%@",fileSize1);
         NSLog(@"***************************");


        NSString *file2 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:filePath1 ofType:@"caf"];
        NSData *file1Data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:file2];

        NSLog(@"**************&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&*************");
        NSLog(@"%@",file1Data);
        NSLog(@"**************&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&**************");
```

===============================================

Now the o/p is

```
2012-11-30 16:39:39.719 Varsity[4802:1a303] /Users/Esolz/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/FAED7832-392C-4BFE-9A9B-D18B749FDC9B/Documents/myVoice.caf
2012-11-30 16:39:39.719 Varsity[4802:1a303] 542752
2012-11-30 16:39:39.719 Varsity[4802:1a303] ***************************
2012-11-30 16:39:39.719 Varsity[4802:1a303] **************&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&*************
2012-11-30 16:39:39.719 Varsity[4802:1a303] (null)
2012-11-30 16:39:39.719 Varsity[4802:1a303] **************&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&**************
```

==============================

actually the main issue is in these two lines

```
NSString *file2 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:filePath1 ofType:@"caf"];
NSData *file1Data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:file2];
```

It is unble to convert the file. Where i m getting wrong

Answer (score 1):

The file is located inside the app sandbox in the Documents Directory and not present in the NSBundle. In simple terms it is not added to your project the way you would include images etc. Hence you are getting the data as null as you are trying to fetch the file data from the project bundle with a path to the documents directory. Try this `NSData *file1Data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath1];`

Comment: ya man, thanks it's working. But the file is converting into binary file and taking too much time to upload. I don't want to convert the file into binary. How can i do this?

Comment: You may take a look at the ASIHTTP library here http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/ , some sample code that I could pull out is like so:  `ASIFormDataRequest *request = [[[ASIFormDataRequest alloc] initWithURL:url] autorelease];
[request setPostValue:@"ABC" forKey:@"filename"];
[request setPostValue:@"caf" forKey:@"format"];
[request setFile:@"/Users/Desktop/Files/Voice.caf" forKey:@"audioFile"];` or the MKNetworkingKit here http://github.com/mugunthkumar/mknetworkkit .HTH